# Multiple editor windows

Tags: xcode, xcode4

One feature I found missing in earlier versions of Xcode 4 was opening an editor as a separate window. Has this feature been put back?

I don't want to go back to MDI hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Xcode preferences window, under general, there is "Double click navigation." You can set that to use a separate window or a separate tab.